# DataTable dropdown option update callback output function

Tags: python, plotly-dash

UPDATED CODE

```
import dash
from dash import Dash, dash_table, dcc, html, Input, Output, State, no_update, callback
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# Create a sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'TeamID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'TeamName': ['Team 1', 'Team 2', 'Team 3', 'Team 4'],
                   'Finished': [1,1,0,1]})

team_select_table = dash_table.DataTable(
        id='team-selection-table',
        editable=True,
        column_selectable="single",
        row_selectable="multi",
        row_deletable=False,
        selected_columns=[],
        page_action="native",
        page_current= 0,
        page_size= 100,
        style_table={'minWidth': '100%'},
        dropdown={},

        style_header={
            'backgroundColor': 'rgb(30, 30, 30)',
            'color': 'white',
            'fontWeight': 'bold',
            'textAlign': 'center'
        },
        style_data={
            'whiteSpace': 'normal',
            'backgroundColor': 'rgb(50, 50, 50)',
            'color': 'white'
        },
        style_data_conditional=[
            {'if': {'column_id': 'TeamID'},
            'width': '10%'},
            {'if': {'column_id': 'TeamName'},
            'width': '10%'},
        ],
        style_cell_conditional=[
            {
                'if': {'column_id': c},
                'textAlign': 'center'
            } for c in ['TeamID', 'TeamName']
        ],
    )

app.layout = html.Div([
    team_select_table,
    html.Div(id='dummy_div'),
])

@app.callback(
    Output('team-selection-table', 'data'),
    Output('team-selection-table', 'columns'),
    Output('team-selection-table', 'dropdown'),
    Output('team-selection-table', 'style_data_conditional'),
    Input('dummy_div', 'children'),
    prevent_initial_call=False,
    background=False,
)
def load_teams(dummy):
    df['Finished'] = df['Finished'].map({1: True, 0: False})  # Convert to boolean values

    df_columns = [{'name': col, 'id': col} for col in df.columns]
    df_data = df.to_dict(orient='records')

    dropdown = {
        'TeamID': {'options': [{'label': str(val), 'value': val} for val in df['TeamID'].unique()]},
        'Finished': {'options': [{'label': 'Yes', 'value': True}, {'label': 'No', 'value': False}]}
    }

    style_data_conditional = [
        {
            'if': {'column_id': 'Finished'},
            'presentation': 'dropdown'
        }
    ]

    return df_data, df_columns, dropdown, style_data_conditional



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8020,debug=True)
```

Given the code above, I've been trying to update the dropdown options inside the datatable for the 'Finished' column. I cannot find an example online of someone doing this but following the references for the datatable, it should be possible. Could someone shed some light on what I'm missing? I've got more code involved but these are the primary pieces that I am having issues with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems.

**1** You reference `dummy_div` in your callback, but this element doesn't exist in the app's layout.

**2** You set `editable` on the `DataTable` to `False`. Dropdowns are for editing so you can't have them if you've disabled editing on the datatable.

**3** In your callback you do this:

```
dropdown = {
    "Finished": {"options": [{"label": i, "value": i} for i in df["Finished"].unique()]}
}

return dropdown
```

If you run the app under debug Dash will tell you:

> Invalid argument `dropdown.Finished.options[0].label` passed into DataTable with ID "team-selection-table".
> Expected `string`.
> Was supplied type `boolean`.

`df["Finished"]` contains boolean values so convert the values to strings before you pass them as labels.

**4** You don't set `data` and `column` properties on the `DataTable`:

```
# Add these
columns=[{"name": column, "id": column, "presentation": "dropdown"} for column in df.columns],
data=df.to_dict('records'),
```

Note the use of `"presentation": "dropdown"`. I'm lazy in the snippet above in that I set `"presentation": "dropdown"` for all columns. In your case you can adjust the list comprehension to only use this for the `"Finished"` column.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. honestly, I wasn't thorough enough when giving this example of the code. I did have the debug set as true, I did have a dummy,I did set the columns and data to dict, and had the Finished values originally as just strings 1's and 0's. I will update my post to have all of the changes. Thank you again!

Comment: My mistake was that I had the datatable in a card and it did not give me the error messages..Now I do. Thank you for that insight.

Comment: could you take another look? I'm still not getting the last note of yours. Could you clarify, please?

Comment: OH SNAP. I got it to work with your column comprehensive list.. I blame the lack of coffee.